# Использование фреймов

Tags: html, css

Вопросов будет два маленьких, недопонимаю некоторые детали.

1. На сайте планируется более 100 страниц, если вдруг я захочу добавить пункт в меню, то придется менять на каждой странице. Целесообразно ли использовать здесь фреймы?
   Второй вопрос странный, но серьёзно не понимаю. Размещение сайта.
2. Все страницы сайта пишу вручную. В какой момент сайт нужно размещать на хостинг, покупать домен, когда будут сделаны полностью все страницы?

Comment: 1. Почему бы и нет? Самое простое из решений для статики. Чуть сложнее - JavaScript (я несколько лет назад делал так: http://www.konf-csu.narod.ru/ze/). 

2. Если сразу хотите делать абсолютные ссылки, то лучше покупкой хостинга и домена озаботиться заранее. Если ссылки - относительные, то не важно.

Answer (score 2):

1. На сайте планируется более 100 страниц, если вдруг я захочу добавить пункт в меню, то придется менять на каждой странице. Целесообразно ли использовать здесь фреймы? Нецелесообразно, хотя можно использовать фреймы, (в одном фрейме меню, а в другом контент, тогда при изменении меню не нужно будет менять по всему сайту. Но фреймы не очень кроссбраузерны,(будет "ехать" верстка) лучше использовать include (php страницу  с меню) например.
2. Купить хостинг и домен лучше заранее, при покупке хостинга нужно учитывать что будете использовать (какова кодировка сайта, будут ли использоваться скрипты форума, гостевой, чата; применяться php, perl, phyton, asp.net итп, а также нужно учесть будущее место для сайта, и трафик. Если сайт небольшой, то 15 - 100 мб хватит для html файлов.

Comment: Т.е. лучше купить хостинг и домен, чтобы "меню" было сразу с ссылками и потом не пришлось размещать эти ссылки на каждой странице?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтоб общий вид везде менялся сразу нужно использовать php.
Вырезать часть документа и поместить ее в файл 
`header.php`,
а на освободившееся место вписать код

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

а также поменять расширение на php